# Chnage the colour of tile for a 'shortcut' pinned to start

Tags: windows-8.1, tiles

I've created a few tiles for shutdown, restart and sleep for Windows 8.1 tile area.

I know you can add an icon, but I'm wondering if you can change the background colour of the tiles? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear that this is currently possible (though I only searched for ~5 minutes). The most useful thing I was able to find was [a forum post here](http://www.eightforums.com/customization/2657-changing-color-tiles-start-menu.html), which seemed to offer the ability to edit tile group colors, if you're willing to edit a system dll file (read: if you're feeling brave/ready to break things). However, it doesn't seem to offer any solution for individual tile colors.

Comment: Poor effort on the part of MS really. Hopefully it'll be addressed in Windows 8.2!!

Comment: Yeah, it's still pretty new, so presumably they haven't had the change to implement some of these more "minor" features.